# Why is my +number in the users list physics SE site less than my +number on my profile?

Tags: discussion

This question is no longer needed because I now know how the system works. Nevertheless, I ask it. It can become more clear to others as well.

One can see on the users' site of physics SE site that my +number is less than on my profile on a yearly base):

Users' list: [image]:

Profile[image]

Can you see the difference? Quite a lot.

Comment: [Your Physics.SE profile](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/98822/descheleschilder) looks fine to me.

Comment: Your Physics.SE rep is 8,341 and counting. Are you sure we're looking at the same thing?

Comment: "My reputation is around +550 while in the list it says +417" What list? Can you link it?

Comment: Take a screenshot of your rep. I see on your profile 8K rep.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, you're referring to [this list](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users). By default, it shows how much rep you've earned in the past month (which is in fact 419).

Comment: "why I've also been removed from this site. I.e. all my questions and comments." You have two accounts, this one https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/98822/descheleschilder and one with no content https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/247178/descheleschilder does that explain your problem with missing content?

Comment: `And why, again, the downvotes?` The downvotes are because you failed to explain adequately the problem.

Comment: You are not removed. I have no slight idea what you're asking, hence I downvoted and voted to close the question as "Needs details or clarity". If you'll edit the question to make more sense, I'll retract both the downvote and the close vote. Cheers.

Comment: There were no pictures until you added them in 7 hours ago, when you posted that comment. And editing a question to ask a completely different question when you already have answers is poor form.

Comment: As I commented on the accepted answer, the "+" number in your profile is the amount of reputation you have gained since your list visit to the rep tab, *not* your yearly rep change. You can confirm this by hovering your mouse cursor over the little green box and reading the tooltip that appears. It's nothing to do with the change in question upvote value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have earned 527 for the *quarter*, while you've earned 419 for the *month*.

[image: week | month | quarter | year]

As you can see, you can choose to sort by week, month, quarter, year, or all. Each of these options will produce a list of users, sorted by their reputation earned in that timeframe.

If you select "month", you'll see this:

[image: showing 419 rep]

...because that's how much rep you've earned in December 2019.

While if you select "quarter" and go to page 3, you see this:

[image: showing 527 rep]

...because that's how much rep you've earned in the last quarter of 2019.

Comment: Well caught young grasshopper ;p

Comment: Very well caught indeed. A pity I can't upvote and accept your answer!

Comment: Why not, @descheleschilder?

Comment: But then again, why it is shown that my reputation change this year is +112, while it is in fact +579

Comment: @descheleschilder [Your reputation change this year](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) is 1,558.

Comment: @Cerbrus My reputation is too low.

Comment: @descheleschilder: You can -always- accept an answer on your own question. You only need __15__ rep to be able to upvote an answer. You can upvote and accept this answer.

Comment: @F1Krazy Not true. Just look for yourself.

Comment: @descheleschilder I did look for myself, and I have linked you to the user table filtered by year that shows your yearly rep change quite clearly. If you're referring to somewhere else this time, you're going to have to tell us where.

Comment: In my profile, you can check it out. It's on a yearly basis.

Comment: @descheleschilder - Your year change is 1556: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaDPg.png

Comment: Okay, but that's, again, to see in the user list but not in my profile.

Comment: Are you referring to the little box with the number in it next to your "Reputation" tab? I believe that's the amount of rep you've earned since the last time you visited your profile, and it's only visible to you.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the Home, Questions, Tags, **users**, unanswered list, to see left above, on this (or on any site?) site. Can you see it here? Somewhat higher above here.

Comment: @descheleschilder: that doesn't mean you can't vote. It just means that the vote isn't publicly counted yet.

Comment: No, truly I can't vote, but that's maybe I've already accepted an answer.

Comment: You said you weren't referring to the user list, and now you're saying you're referring to the user list? I'm afraid you've compeltely lost me. Please provide a screenshot of what you are seeing and explain **clearly** what you think it should be showing that it isn't showing, and why you think it should be showing that.

Answer (score 5):

Actually - from your profile, your [physics account](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/98822/descheleschilder) looks... intact?

I don't see any other accounts on your IP either. You do have one off topic question ([deleted as per our usual process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324004/how-can-tv-companies-make-ads-for-their-newest-tvs-on-the-old-tv-you-own)) . That would indicate though, that your last activity here on that account was in Febuary

The one possibility I am thinking of is getting logged out, and/or using an unregistered account - but that's a pretty messy set of circumstances.

Comment: YES! BUT...My reputation in the Physics SE site has been shown to be +417 while in fact, it is +587!

Comment: ..... You have 8k reputation

Comment: post a screenshot, because I see 8K rep too.

Comment: No. I've have already the answer I needed.